# MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to the "Koopa Troopa" game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm replicating Super Mario game. And currently getting an error as below:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to
> the "Gumbaa" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You
> probably need to add a SpriteRenderer to the game object "Koopa
> Troopa". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached
> before using it. UnityEngine.Renderer.get_bounds () (at
> /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/GraphicsBindings.gen.cs:1007)
> EnemyMovement.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/EnemyMovement.cs:21)

And my game also got automatically pause whenever I clicked play button.

[image: Screenshot of inspector]

Here is full script:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 2.7f;
    public LayerMask EnemyMask;

    Transform myTrans;
    float myWidth, myHeight;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer mySprite;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        myTrans = this.transform;
        rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

        mySprite = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        myWidth = mySprite.bounds.extents.x;
        myHeight = mySprite.bounds.extents.y;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (8, 9);
        Vector2 LineCastPos = (myTrans.position.toVector2() +     myTrans.right.toVector2() * myWidth + Vector2.up * myHeight * 1.2f);

        Debug.DrawLine (LineCastPos, LineCastPos +      myTrans.right.toVector2 () * 1.2f);

        bool isBlocked = Physics2D.Linecast (LineCastPos, LineCastPos + myTrans.right.toVector2 () * 1.2f, EnemyMask);


        if (isBlocked) 
        {
            Vector2 currRot = myTrans.eulerAngles;
            currRot.y += 180;
            myTrans.eulerAngles = currRot;
        }

        Vector2 myVel = rb.velocity;
        myVel.x = myTrans.right.x * speed ;
        rb.velocity = myVel;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a snapshot of the gameobject inspector? the solution is in the error - the gameobject with this script attached to it also needs a SpriteRenderer component attached to it. You also don't need `this.` in front of `gameObject.GetComponent...`.

Comment: Dear @ryeMoss ive attached the screenshot in the form of link :) Thanks!

Comment: okay, then the solution is still the same - you need to attach a SpriteRenderer to the gameobject