# There is no Rigidbody 2D attached to the game object but the script is trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code I'm using. It throws a `MissingComponentException`: There is no Rigidbody 2D attached to "Bird" game object but the script is trying to access it.

```
using System.Collections;

public class Bird : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float UpForce;                   //Upward force of the "flap".
    private bool _isDead = false;           //Has the player collided with a wall?

    private Animator _anim;                 //Reference to the Animator component.
    private Rigidbody2D _rb2d;              //Holds a reference to the Rigidbody2D component of the bird.

    void Start()
    {
        //Get reference to the Animator component attached to this GameObject.
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        //Get and store a reference to the Rigidbody2D attached to this GameObject.
        _rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Don't allow control if the bird has died.
        if (_isDead == false) 
        {
            //Look for input to trigger a "flap".
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            {
                //...tell the animator about it and then...
                _anim.SetTrigger("Flap");
                //...zero out the birds current y velocity before...
                _rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                //  new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, 0);
                //..giving the bird some upward force.
                _rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, UpForce));
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        // Zero out the bird's velocity
        _rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        // If the bird collides with something set it to dead...
        _isDead = true;
        //...tell the Animator about it...
        _anim.SetTrigger ("Die");
        //...and tell the game control about it.
        GameControl.instance.BirdDied ();
    }
}
```

How do I provide the reference it wants?

Answer (score 0):

The GameObject this script is attached to should have a RigidBidy2D component (because the script is using it to apply forces to GameObject). You can either add a Rigidbody2D in inspector (choose the GameObject the script is attached to and use "Add Component" menu), or make it so the script adds a component automatically when you attach it to GameObject by adding a [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) attribute like this:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //your Bird class code here
}
```

See also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288302/there-is-no-renderer-attached-to-the-robot2-game-object-but-a-script-is-try) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312606/missingcomponentexception-there-is-no-spriterenderer-attached-to-the-koopa-t) - that's the same problem.